# How to extract URL from different types of hyperlinked text?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have collected hyperlinked text data from different souces. I have copied and pasted it to cell B5:B ([spreadsheet attached](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1awenVLUKvIcHfL-9JrFU76RFSKEKErV5sNtJ0VEW_L4/edit#gid=0)). there is two types of data, one is pasted to B5:B11 and other is pasted into B14:B18. To extract the URL, i have created a script

```
const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const hyperlinks = sheet.getRange("B5:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().map(([c]) => [c.getLinkUrl() || null]);
  sheet.getRange(5, 4, hyperlinks.length).setValues(hyperlinks);
}
```

The above code works for the cell B14:B18. But unfortunately, it is not able to extract hyperlink from the cell B5:B11. So, kindly help me to extracting hyperlinked data types as given in B5:B11.
the data given in B5:B11 is

[008GPGNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-08GPG/)

[008MPDNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-08MPD/)

[111AGGNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-11AGG/)

[111AMDNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-11AMD/)

[111DPDNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-11DPD/)

[111DPRNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-11DPR/)

[111GPGNIPPON INDIA MUTUAL FUNDD](https://in.tradingview.com/symbols/BSE-11GPG/)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about using `getRun` as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const hyperlinks = sheet.getRange("B5:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().map(([c]) =>
    [c.getRuns().map(r => [r.getLinkUrl() || null]).filter(String).join(",")]
  );
  sheet.getRange(5, 4, hyperlinks.length).setValues(hyperlinks);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your provided Spreadsheet, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [getRuns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value#getRuns())

Answer (score 0):

you've provided a Google Apps Script that aims to extract hyperlinks from a specific range in a Google Sheets document. This script uses the 'getRichTextValues' method to retrieve the rich text (including hyperlinks) from the specified range and then extracts the URLs using 'getLinkUrl()'.

Comment: But, my problem is that it could not be able to extract/retrieve some especial type of hyperlinked text.