extract hyperlink with google sheets
I have been using this Apps Script for Google Sheets to extract a hyperlink from a cell:
function extractUrl(input) {
  var url = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(input).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl();
  return url;
} 

The function (in column C) has been working flawlessly with the hyperlink in cell B1 but for some reason it doesn't in cell B2! I am no Apps Script expert. Could you please help me extract a hyperlink from cell B2 as well?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ihKbWDOsQHDQz-xPx9FFQYxLDXYqWyM8Zf_okxjZ_o/edit?usp=sharing

I guess that this thread might be an answer to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77824028

Did you make a change to the linked spreadsheet? I'm asking because C2 is showing the URL of B2, so apparently, it's working now.

It's worth noting that questions on this site should be self-contained, but in case there is no other way to provide enough details to reproduce the issue, please ensure that the linked resource stays unaltered; otherwise, the question becomes "not reproducible".

getLinkUrl() returns the link URL or null if there is no link or if there are multiple different links.
In cell B2 this is exactly the case when getLinkUrl() returns null.
If you look closely at the hyperlink preview, you can see the difference between the link text (20/20 Robotics) and the text in the cell (20/20 Robotics Booth #3055).

This can also be seen by the color of the text in the preview. The part of the text to which the hyperlink is attached is blue (20/20 Robotics). The remaining part (Booth #3055) is black.
In this case, there is more than one link in the cell, so getLinkUrl() cannot be used.
getLinkUrl(startOffset, endOffset) will help here.
The code below iterates through each character of the link text and extracts the URL. If the URL is not null and is not in the array, the URL is pushed to the array. As a result, all elements of the array are separated by a double line break and are output.
This way you can extract multiple hyperlinks from a single cell.
Try:
function extractUrl(input) {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getActiveSheet().getRange(input);

  var richTextValue = range.getRichTextValue();
  var length = richTextValue.getText().length;
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = length; i > 0; i--) {
    var url = richTextValue.getLinkUrl(i - 1, i);
    if (url && arr.indexOf(url) < 0) arr.push(url);
  }
  return arr.join("\n\n");
}



Good catch. I didn't expand the cell, so never noticed "why" the issue existed.

Two Issues

FIRST ISSUE
There is an issue with your link in Sheets, perhaps related to the way it was added to the sheet, and your script is not able to retrieve it (returns null).

This can be remedied by opening the link to edit it and, without changing anything, save it.



SECOND ISSUE Sheets won't trigger a refresh of the custom function when you edit the URL

You can work around this by adding a toggle checkbox to your sheet for example in D2 and instead of calling your function using
=extractUrl("B2") 

Use:
=IF($D$2, extractUrl("B2"), "-") 

In this way whenever you want to refresh the URL(s) you simply toggle the checkbox off and back on. You can use a single checkbox for all instances of your formula.





This simple expression worked for me
=B2.URL

A code only answer has limited value for the OP as well as future users. Would you please explain how this code fits within the OP's scenario and demonstrate a successful outcome.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
